# Limiting the result to top four in xquery

Tags: xpath, xquery, zorba

```
<a>
{
for $o in doc("x.xml")/users/org
where fn:count($o/mem)
order by fn:count($o/mem) descending
return <org>
            <b> {$o/@name/string()} </b>
            <c> {$o/@ab/string()} </c>
            <d> {fn:count($o/mem)} </d>
       </org>
}
</a>
```

I have ordered the results in an descending order but I just need top 4 result from this. I tried to use the sub-sequence method on the wiki page and also the [position() 1,4] method to find the top 4 but was not successful.

Comment: Minor observation, `where fn:count($o/mem)` seems a little perverse. You can write `where exists($o/mem)` or even `where $o/mem`, or just add the condition to the initial selection: `for $o in doc('x.xml')/users/org[mem]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way using two `for` loops and limit the inner `for` to return only the first 4 results :

```
<a>
{
    for $p in
    (
        for $o in doc("x.xml")/users/org
        where fn:count($o/mem)
        order by fn:count($o/mem) descending
        return <org>
                    <b> {$o/@name/string()} </b>
                    <c> {$o/@ab/string()} </c>
                    <d> {fn:count($o/mem)} </d>
               </org>
    )[position() <= 4]
    return $p
}
</a>
```

**update :**

Turns out that we don't actually need the outer `for` :

```
<a>
{
    (
        for $o in doc("x.xml")/users/org
        where fn:count($o/mem)
        order by fn:count($o/mem) descending
        return <org>
                    <b> {$o/@name/string()} </b>
                    <c> {$o/@ab/string()} </c>
                    <d> {fn:count($o/mem)} </d>
               </org>
    )[position() <= 4]
}
</a>
```

Comment: The updated one did not work (Error Message: static error [err:XPST0003]: invalid expression: syntax error, unexpected "="
) but the first one worked well.

Comment: @crash my mistake, needed `{}` wrapping the entire query to make it work. Tested here with different XML structure : http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/53d30fe783467d8f1ecb525449b9d134